# How to attach events on window.opener

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a window that is opened by

```
var myWindow = window.open(
                  'popupManager.htm', 
                  'myWindow', 
                  'status=0,toolbar=0,width=500,height=100');
```

and it will act as a debug window.

inside I want to hook up to windows events on the `window.opener` and I'm not getting this to work. Both URL's are in the same domain/same website.

I can hook up to DOM elements fine using, for example

```
$("input[soid=DlgButtonBar_cancelButton]", window.opener.document).bind("click", function() {
    alert('Cancel button was pressed!');
    window.close();
});
```

but I want to hook up to the `move` event (`window.onMove`) and `close` event.

tried

```
window.opener.addEventListener('move', function() { console.log('moving...'); });
```

with no luck.

**what is the trick?** using jQuery or simple javascript...

Comment: Why aren't you using `bind` for the `move` event?

Comment: cause it doesn't work if you passe `window.opener` like `$(window.opener).bind("move", function() { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Listening on window events doesn't seem to work. I use this trick to listen to **window** events (unload in my case):

1. Create a document element (e.g. span) on the parent document (e.g. the one you want to get events from) :

   ```
   var $unloader = $('<span style="display:none;" id="unloader"></span>');
   $('body').prepend($unloader');    
   $(window).unload(function(){$('#unloader').click();});
   ```
2. In the opened document (e.g. popout), you can listen to the **unload** event now masked as a **click** event:

   ```
   $("#unloader",window.opener.document).click(unloadEventHandler);
   ```

If you need to detect if the **unload** is a close or a navigation event, you can check the closed property for the parent after a delay:

```
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        if(window.opener.closed == true) {
             // Close event
        } else {
            // Navigation event
            // window.opener.location to get new location
        }
    },500);
```

The risk is in the delay, the **closed** property is changed after the unload methods and event hooks are executed so if the delay is too short you might get the flag before it is changed and if it's too long, you get unnecessary delays.

I think the **move** event can be handled similarly, hope this helps. Let me know if there are any possible improvements to this method. Thanks and good luck.